# Is it possible to use the kafka-console-producer to send messages via a transactional client?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to use the kafka-console-producer cli tool to send messages to a topic using a transactional client. I think I have the configuration correct for this, but when I run the cli tool, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform a 'send' before completing a call to initTransactions when transactions are enabled.
```

So, it would appear that the kafka-console-producer, which I believe instantiates the kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer class, is either not calling initTransactions, or is sending before the call completes.

Is there something I can do to get the the kafka-console-producer cli to send to a topic using transactions?

Here is the command line I use to run the kafka-console-producuer:

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/tmp/kafka/jaas.conf";echo "test message" | kafka-console-producer --broker-list wildthing-2.gce.cloudera.com:9092 --topic ${topic}  --producer.config /tmp/kafka/client.properties
```

I am using Kafka version 2.2.1.
Here is the producer config from the resulting output:

```
21/04/01 14:58:41 INFO producer.ProducerConfig: ProducerConfig values: 
        acks = all
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [wildthing-2.gce.cloudera.com:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = console-producer
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        linger.ms = 1000
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 1500
        retries = 3
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = kafka
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = 123
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

Comment: You could use kafkacat, which supports EOS now, I think

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a cli tool [kcat](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat) should provide the ability to produce messages transactionally. In the case of writing the new Java producer we had a similar problem in Nussknacker where you can check how to manager Kafka producer transaction and how to set up producer options.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben, You are right. The cli kafka-console-producer calls the scala class kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer. As per my understanding, only the new Java producer and consumer support exactly-once semantics. Please refer to [this](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#upgrade_11_exactly_once_semantics) documentation for more details. So to answer your question directly - No, I don't think you can do something to get the out of the box cli kafka-console-producer to send messages transactionally. However, you can write your own producer using the new Java producer API and call that from a shell script.